# Rendering fails with no GLErrors Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am running on the same issue for 2 days now. I am trying to render the usual 2D triangle (in 3D space) in OpenGL ES 2.0, on android (minApi 15, target 23). I have rewritten the entire code twice, and i get always the same results. No OpenGL Errors or warnings, no Java exceptions, and the screen is just black....
Anyway here's the code for the renderer class, the activity just creates the renderer and calls `start()` in the `onCreate()`.

```
import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;
public class renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private Activity a;
    private GLSurfaceView v;
    private int buffs[];
    private int prg;

    private static boolean checkGLError(){
        int i = glGetError();
        if(i != GL_NO_ERROR){
             Log.e("GLError", "Error: " + i);
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String VShaderSource =
                "precision  highp       float;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "attribute  mat4        mVP;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "attribute  vec3        vPos;\n" +
                "attribute  vec3        col;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying    vec3        oCol;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main(){\n" +
                "   gl_Position = mVP * vec4(vPos, 1.0);\n" +
                "   oCol = col;\n" +
                "}";
    private String FShaderSource =
                "precision  mediump     float;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying    vec3        oCol;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main(){\n" +
                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(oCol, 255);\n" +
                "}";

    public renderer(Activity a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void start(){
        v = new GLSurfaceView(this.a);
        v.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        v.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        v.setRenderer(this);
        v.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        a.setContentView(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.w("OGL Renderer", "OnSUfraceCreated Called!");
        int vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vs, VShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(vs);
        int var[] = new int[1];
        glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, var, 0);
        if(var[0] != GL_TRUE){
            Log.e("OGL Shader", "VShader error: " + glGetShaderInfoLog(vs));
        }else{
            Log.w("OGL Shader", "VShader compiled successfully");
        }

        glShaderSource(fs, FShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(fs);
        glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, var, 0);
        if(var[0] != GL_TRUE){
            Log.e("OGL Shader", "FShader error: " + glGetShaderInfoLog(fs));
        }else{
            Log.w("OGL Shader", "FShader compiled successfully");
        }

        prg = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(prg, vs);
        glAttachShader(prg, fs);
        glLinkProgram(prg);
        glGetProgramiv(prg, GL_LINK_STATUS, var, 0);
        if(var[0] != GL_TRUE){
            Log.e("OGL Shader", "Linker error: " + glGetProgramInfoLog(prg));
        }else{
            Log.w("OGL Shader", "Program compiled successfully");
        }
        glUseProgram(prg);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during Program initialization");
        }
        float[] vertices = {-100, -100, -1,
                        100, -100, -1,
                        0, 100, -1};
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer vFb = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vFb.put(vertices);
        vFb.position(0);
        float[] colors = {1, 0, 0,
                        0, 1, 0,
                        0, 0, 1};
        ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer cFb = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        cFb.put(colors);
        cFb.position(0);
        buffs = new int[2];
        glGenBuffers(2, buffs, 0);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during Buffer generation");
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffs[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vFb.capacity(), vFb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during GLBufferData 1");
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffs[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cFb.capacity(), cFb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during GLBufferData 2");
        }
        int mPos = glGetUniformLocation(prg, "mVP");
        float[] projection = new float[16], view = new float[16], mVP = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(projection, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(view, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.perspectiveM(projection, 0, 90.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.000001f, 1000.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mVP, 0, projection, 0, view, 0);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mPos, 1, false, mVP, 0);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during matrix load");
        }
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        glViewPort(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        int vPos, cPos;
        vPos = glGetAttribLocation(prg, "vPos");
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during GetAttribLocation 1");
        }
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);
        cPos = glGetAttribLocation(prg, "col");
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during GetAttribLocation 2");
        }
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(cPos);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffs[0]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during VertexAttribPointer 1");
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffs[1]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(cPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during VertexAttribPointer 2");
        }
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);
        if(checkGLError()){
            Log.e("Error", "GLError during DrawArrays");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
-John

**EDIT** I copied the wrong vertex Z positions, it did not change anything tough

**EDIT 2** Added the `glEnableVertexArrtibArray()` calls, still not working

Comment: `vec4(oCol, 255)` looks strange. Normally colors and transparency in OpenGL is defined by floats between [0,1].

Comment: tried that. didn't work anyway

Comment: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);` draws just one vertex. Since you try to draw triangles, you need at least 3 vertices: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`

Comment: I'll try when Android Studio will stop f*****g up everything, gimme a couple of minutes

Comment: Nope, didn't fix, and i also added the required `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` before the `glVertexAttribPointer()`

Comment: Also tried remaking the thing in the NDK, no luck... I can't figure out what i am missing!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. I was creating a very large triangle, using smaller points (1.0f ~ 10.0f) solved the issue. Also, moved the view matrix a bit further away.